# Dialyzer simplifies long union types

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

I've noticed that Dialyzer possibly simplifies long union types, at least when it comes to atoms.

For example, if I have:

```
defmodule Foo do
  @type name() :: :one | :two | :three

  @spec bar(name()) :: String.t()
  def bar(name), do: to_string(name)
end
```

and then I call the function with

`Foo.bar(:hello)`

Dialyzer will catch the error saying that `:hello` is a wrong type for this function.

But then, if I change the type declaration to make the union consist of more than 13 (my observation) items (pseudo code):

```
@type name() :: :one | :two | :three ... :fourteen
```

Dialyzer seems to convert it into a simple `atom()` type under the hood and would not complain about calling `Foo.bar/1` with any atom, even if it's not included into the union.

So I wonder if that's expected behaviour and whether there's a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a mention of it in the documentation, but this behavior is mentioned in the [Success Typing paper](http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/papers/succ_types.pdf) explaining dialyzer:

> We allow for any disjoint union, including unions of singleton types such as 1 ∪ 2.
> Since these unions can become large or even infinite, in our analysis
> we impose a fixed size limit after which the union is widened to a
> supertype. For example, if the union limit is three the union type
> 1 ∪ 2 ∪ 3 ∪ 4 will be widened to integer ().

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any [option](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) to change this limit as of today.